# Python summation with args parameter

Tags: python, args

```
def asterisk_test(c, b, *args):
  a + b + sum(args)
  
print(asterisk_test(1,2,3,4,5))
```

It makes error called

`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`

so I tried changing tuple to list

```
def asterisk_test(c, b, *args):
  a + b + sum(list(args))
  
print(asterisk_test(1,2,3,4,5))
```

but it makes same error message.

Why python recognize tuple type as "Nonetype"?

Comment: Sometime earlier you assigned the variable `sum`, so it no longer holds the summing function.

Comment: Why do you think the error has something to do with `args`? You're not trying to call `args`, you're trying to call `sum`. The error means that `sum == None`.

Comment: Search your code for `sum =` and change that variable name to something that doesn't conflict with a Python built-in function.

Comment: BTW, shouldn't `a + b` be `c + b`?

Comment: @Barmar: Or they did the same to `print`. Or reassigned `asterisk_test` and didn't tell us. Either way, they forgot to `return` the summed value, so it wouldn't do much useful.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Anything is possible, but `sum` is a very likely variable name if you don't know about the redefinition problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that you have assigned `sum` to something earlier in your code. The code I have provided below represents that. Although `sum` might not be directly assigned to `None`.

```
sum = None
def asterisk_test(c, b, *args):
    print(c+b+sum(args))
  
print(asterisk_test(1,2,3,4,5))
```

So if we try the above code we will get `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable` because python thinks we are doing `None(args)`. So what I suggest you do is look through your code and search for anytime you define `sum`. Change that variable name, don't use names such as `tuples, list, sum` etc.